# MySQL - Display data accurately by fiscal_year

Tags: mysql, database, pivot-table, aggregate-functions

looking for help. This is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE `net_savings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `monthname` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fiscal_year` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(30,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `net_savings_id_unique` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

My data:

```
    INSERT INTO `net_savings` VALUES  
(10,1,'January','2016',-1291.47,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(11,1,'February','2017',389296.02,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(12,1,'March','2018',216143.70,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(13,2,'April','2019',53840.00,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(14,2,'May','2017',1669693.00,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(15,2,'June','2018',1980328.00,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(16,2,'July','2019',2428559.00,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(17,3,'August','2016',963.32,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(18,3,'September','2017',3960.93,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(19,4,'October','2016',-261.74,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(20,4,'November','2017',24160.80,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(21,4,'December','2018',24160.80,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(22,4,'January','2019',8053.60,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(23,5,'February','2016',8846.54,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(24,5,'March','2017',41141.34,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(25,5,'April','2018',41141.34,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(26,5,'May','2019',41141.34,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(27,5,'June','2020',27427.56,'2016-08-30 04:00:00','2016-08-30 04:00:00'),
(31,1,'March','2016',100.00,'2016-09-14 11:33:48','2016-09-14 11:33:48');
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `financial_forecast_yearly`()
BEGIN
SET group_concat_max_len=2048;
SET @sql = NULL;

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
                'MAX(IF(n.fiscal_year = ''',
                n.fiscal_year, ''', n.amount, NULL))AS ',
                    CONCAT("'","FY_",n.fiscal_year,"'"))) 
    INTO @sql
    FROM net_savings n join accounts a
    ON n.account_id = a.id;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT a.id,
                            a.account, 
                            a.region, 
                            SUM(n.amount) as total_net_savings,'
                            ,@sql,
                            'FROM net_savings n  join accounts a
                            on  n.account_id = a.id
                            GROUP BY a.account, n.account_id 
                            ORDER BY a.id');

PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
END
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

However, the data displayed was not accurate. for instance, I have the same input of amount in somewhere in march 2016, the total was not sum up to the column FY2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That stored procedure is complicated and hard to puzzle out!

You're trying to do two things:

1. you're trying to aggregate by fiscal year.
2. you're trying to pivot the results.

It's best to handle these in two steps.

First: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26179/3/0)

```
SELECT SUM(amount) amount,
       account_id, fiscal_year
  FROM net_savings 
 GROUP BY account_id, fiscal_year WITH ROLLUP
```

Second, pivoting is a major pain in the neck in MySQL.

You probably need something like this:

```
SELECT account_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fiscal_year IS NULL THEN amount ELSE 0 END) total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fiscal_year = 2016 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) fy2016,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fiscal_year = 2017 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) fy2017,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fiscal_year = 2018 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) fy2018,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fiscal_year = 2019 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) fy2019,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fiscal_year = 2020 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) fy2020
 FROM (
               SELECT SUM(amount) amount,
                     account_id, fiscal_year
                FROM net_savings 
            GROUP BY account_id, fiscal_year WITH ROLLUP
      ) summary
WHERE account_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY account_id
```

Once you know that's your target statement, then you can write your stored procedure to create it and prepare it.

Comment: Thank you! That worked if I have a static fiscal year, but if I add fiscal year 2021, it will not show up. The reason why I'm pivoting is to make it dynamic as possible.

Comment: Exactly. Some other DBMSs offer pivoting commands, but not MySQL. For example, PostgreSQL : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: Trying to combine my account table but account field is not recognize.